# how many graphs with 10 nodes and 2 edges

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorics

Preparing for exam I have a problem with the following exercise:
How many undirected graphs with exactly 10 nodes and 2 edges exist?

My approach:
I need 3 or 4 nodes to draw 2 edges.
So I have 

10 choose 3 = 120

And 10 choose 4 = 210 

= 330 possibilities?!

Is that correct or did I miss something?

**Edit:** orphaned nodes are allowed

Comment: Does your definition of graph include orphaned nodes? If not, the answer is 0, since as you state there's a max of 4 nodes with 2 edges.

Comment: is it possible for duplicate edges between nodes?

Comment: more important, what does "how many" mean?  What's your idea of two graphs being "the same" (i.e. isomorphic).  Otherwise I'm just going to say infinitely many such graphs exist just by rearranging the points, making them slightly farther apart, etc.

Comment: @djechlin graph theory doesn't mean "on a Cartesian graph"

Comment: Not sure I understand the downvote here. Sure, there's no code, but it's actually quite rare to see homework with 1) a decent description of the problem, 2) an explanation of what was tried and how it was achieved, and 3) actually asking for what was missed. Not saying it's a perfectly phrased question, but this is in like... the top 95% of homework questions we get here, for serious.

Comment: fyi I've not downvoted.  Yes I know we don't mean on paper here, it was the extreme end of what "isomorphic" might mean.  But when I think of two graphs being the same I mean the vertices/edges structure being the same, so in this case the answer would be 3 (`V`, `| |`, `D` if you get my drift).  I think the OP means to fix the nodes and ask about edge structures on top of those but that should be clarified, and I do truly think it's ambiguous for whether the `D` graph is legal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not far.

Case #1: 3 nodes connected togheter. Once you chose the 3 nodes, you have to choose which one is going to be in the middle

case #2: 2 pair of distinct nodes connected. Once you choose the 4 nodes, you still have to choose how they are going to be connected.

A simpler way, though, would be to compute the total number of possible edges: 10 choose 2.
And then, among those possibilities, choose two among them.

Comment: So I have to multiply my results with the below options before adding them together?

case 1#: to pick the center element I have 3 choose 2  = 3 options? 
case 2#: and for the two distinct pairs I have 4 choose 2 = 6 options?

Comment: First case is right, Second case not exactly... You could draw the possible ways of pairing 4 nodes...

Comment: Ok  I think I got it:  2# case:  A -- B , C -- D or A -- C , B -- D or A -- D , B -- C   == 3 Options 
So the final result is 120 * 3  + 210 * 3 = 990 possible graphs?

Comment: thank you, it's clearer to me now! But I have a question to your second approach: 10 choose 2 = 450.  When I now select 2 Edges from the possible 450, that would be 450 choose 2, way more than the result  we've got in the 1 approach, wouldn't it?

Comment: -.- stupid mistake, time for a break. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, which may be completely off base, is you have two options:

```
A---B
|
C
```

and

```
A---B

C---D
```

In both cases, there's 90 `A---B` combinations (10 * 9).

In the first case, there are 8 options for C, and it can connect to either A or B, so you have `10 * 9 * 8 * 2 = 1440` graphs.

In the second case, there are are 8 options for C and 7 options for D, so you have `10 * 9 * 8 * 7 = 5040` graphs. The sum of these is 6480 graphs.

This does **not** handle the case where the two edges are both connecting the same nodes (`A==B`).